# Problems of Compilation in Liferay7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7.2

I have created the module attached by mail in liferay and developed in eclipse and executed the following commands for compiling it :

```
blade gw jar
o el comando 
gradlew distBundle
```

I have the following build.gradle file :

```
dependencies {
compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: '4.33.0'

compileOnly group: "javax.ws.rs", name: "javax.ws.rs-api", version: '2.1.1'
compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.core", version: "6.0.0"
compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.component.annotations",version: '1.3.0'
compileOnly group: "org.osgi", name: "org.osgi.service.jaxrs",version: '1.0.0'

compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.asset.category.property.api",version: '2.1.3'
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.api",version: '6.0.1'
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.journal.api",version: '2.1.0'

compileOnly group: "javax.servlet", name: "javax.servlet-api",version: '4.0.1'

}
```

Whe I compile I have the following error :

```
C:\Users\usuario\Documents\LiferayA1CuatroOchenta\modules\modulo-rest-gestion-contenidos\cuatroochenta-rest\src\main\java\com\cuatro\ochenta\onesignal\listener\AvisoListener.java:55: error: cannot access CTModel
                if (Objects.equals(avisoStructureId, ddmStructure.getStructureId())) {
                                  ^
  class file for com.liferay.portal.kernel.model.change.tracking.CTModel not found
C:\Users\usuario\Documents\LiferayA1CuatroOchenta\modules\modulo-rest-gestion-contenidos\cuatroochenta-rest\src\main\java\com\cuatro\ochenta\rest\resource\AgendaTematicaResource.java:69: error: cannot access CTService
                DDMStructure ddmStructure = _ddmStructureLocalService.getDDMStructure(GetterUtil.getLong(PropsUtil.get("agenda.tematica.structure.id")));
                                                                     ^
  class file for com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.change.tracking.CTService not found
2 errors
```

Whe I execute the following command :

```
gradle gw jar
```

The JournalArticle class cannot get the CTmodel
I have used the following Liferay version: 7.2.0-ga1

I have attached main files in the module folder.

Comment: as your files store in C drive. There might be a permission issue. Try in a different drive.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824